# Chebyshev Polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to prove a something regarding Chebyshev polynomials. Given the polynomials $T_n(x), n = 0, 1, \ldots$ which are recursively defined by
$$\begin{cases} T_0(x) = 1\\ T_1(x) = x \\T_n(x) = 2x T_{n−1}(x) − T_{n−2}(x), & \text{for } n \geq 2\end{cases}$$

I want to show that

For every $n$, $$T_n(x) = \cos(n \arccos(x))$$

Is there some type of proof I could use or is just plugging in values the only way?

Comment: Show that $\cos (n \arccos (x))$ satisfies the recursive definition.

Comment: So do I set it equal to the recursive definition?

Comment: No, you show that it satisfies the recursive definition. In other words, set $P_n(x) = \cos (n \arccos x)$ and show that $P_0(x) = 1, P_1(x) = x, P_n(x) = 2x P_{n-1}(x) - P_{n-2}(x)$. By induction, it then follows that $T_n(x) = P_n(x)$. (You already need induction to show that a recursive definition is actually a definition of anything so this should not be too surprising.)

Comment: Should that be P(n-2)?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: I am getting: 
2xcos(n*arccosx-arccosc) - cos(n*arcosx - 2arccosx), is there an angle property I need to use?

Comment: You can solve Chebyshev's equation using the change of variables: $x=\cos t$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plugging in values will only prove finitely many instances.

This is a sequence of trigonometric identities.  Since it's a definition by recursion, you do the proof by mathematical induction.  It's obviously true if $n=0$ or $1$.  So suppose it's true in the first $n$ cases, so you know
$$
T_n(\cos\theta) = \cos(n\theta).
$$
and similarly for $n-1$.

You want to prove
$$
T_{n+1}(\cos\theta) = \cos((n+1)\theta).
$$

So write
$$
\begin{align}
T_{n+1}(\cos\theta) & = 2(\cos\theta) T_n(\cos\theta) - T_{n-1}(\cos\theta) \\[8pt]
& = 2(\cos\theta)(\cos(n\theta)) - \cos((n-1)\theta) \\[8pt]
& = 2(\cos\theta)(\cos(n\theta)) - \Big( \cos(n\theta)\cos\theta + \sin(n\theta)\sin\theta \Big) \\[8pt]
& = (\cos\theta)(\cos(n\theta)) -\sin(n\theta)\sin\theta \\[8pt]
& = \cos((n+1)\theta).
\end{align}
$$

(Of course, you have to remember some basic trigonometric identities to follow this.)

Comment: I was able to follow, thank you!

Comment: Shouldnt it be Tn(theta) and not cos(theta)?

Comment: @SamuelGregory : No, the argument above won't work in that case.  Just let $x=\cos\theta$, so $\theta=\arccos x$ and $T_n(x)=T_n(\cos\theta)$.

Answer (score 3):

I had to answer this question even though its years late :P

$$ \cos\left((n+1)\theta\right) = \cos(n\theta + \theta) = \cos(n\theta)\cos(\theta) - \sin(n\theta) \sin(\theta) \\ 
\cos\left((n-1)\theta\right) = \cos(n\theta - \theta) = \cos(n\theta)\cos(\theta) + \sin(n\theta) \sin(\theta) $$

Now if you add the left and right sides of this equation you get:

$$
\cos((n+1)\theta) + \cos((n-1)\theta) = 2 \cos(n\theta) \cos(\theta)
$$

If you let $x = \cos(\theta)$ and $T_n(x) = \cos(n\theta)$, you get:

$$
T_{n+1} + T_{n-1} = 2 x T_{n}
$$

So we have:

$$
T_{n+1} = 2 x T_{n}  -T_{n-1}
$$

Which is equivalent to what you asked :)